# Не могу понять MVC в PHP

Tags: php, mvc

На просторах сети, спустя очень большой объём времени, мне удалось найти самый простой пример шаблона проектирования MVC в PHP. Но я никак не могу понять его логики. Куда двигаться дальше, куда заполнять контент и как это делать в соответствии с шаблоном. Помогите понять. Уже несколько недель пытаюсь понять его, а никак.
Сам пример:

```
class Model
{
  public $text;

  public function __construct()
  {

    $this->text = 'Hello World!';

  }

}

class View
{

  private $model;

  public function __construct(Model $model)
  {

    $this->model = $model;

  }

  public function output()
  {

    return '<a href="index.php?action=textclicked">' . $this->model->text . '</a>';

  }

}

class Controller
{

  private $model;

  public function __construct(Model $model)
  {

    $this->model = $model;

  }

  public function textClicked()
  {

    $this->model->text = 'Text Updated';

  }

}

$model = new Model();

$controller = new Controller($model);

$view = new View($model);

if (isset($_GET['action']))
{

  $controller->{$_GET['action']}();

}

echo $view->output();
```

Я не понимаю что выполняет команда:

```
class Controller
{

  private $model;

  public function __construct(Model $model)
  {

    $this->model = $model;

  }
```

Я не понимаю кто кого и как загружает. Вообще ничего непонятно(

Comment: А что именно вы хотите сделать? В чем проблема и что вы именно не понимаете? Опишите больше деталей в вопрос.

Comment: @And, я дополнил вопрос. Теперь сможете как-нибудь помочь?

Comment: Вот же нормальное описание https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller

Comment: `Controller` принимает объект `Model` и присваивает свойству `$this->model`. Что тут непонятного? Не понимаю :) А ваш `Model` может быть собран как угодно, а после разобран в `Controller` как нужно с проверками и условиями.

Comment: Понятнее не стало

Comment: Вы нашли не простой пример) А, что видео уже отменили? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ba3M3_Myrqg&list=PLSdH7dYnlGYgQ6ElbHRpG2zRXbkgkO3zQ Самое лучшее объяснение про **MVC**, которое я встречал)

Comment: А вы много раз прочитайте и поймете. Хотя, раз за 2 недели не разобрались, значит вам с трудом дается программирование. Ну если сильно захотеть, можно в космос полететь, так и тут, было бы у вас желание. вы бы и за 2 дней разобрались, а то и за день. Читайте больше книг.

Answer (score 5):

Давайте попробуй доступно объяснить, **свое представление**:

`MVC`- это **идея**, не **реализация**, не набор из 3-ех классов и т.д. Это абстрактная концепция которая помогает решить архитектурные вопросы Вашего проекта предложенным путем.

Самая распространенная версия `MVC` выглядит так: поступает запрос (например запрос главной страницы сайта), Ваш скрипт запускает контроллер для главной. Контроллер в данном случае тот кусок кода, который отвечает за логику, логика в данном случае - показать пользователю главную страницу. Для формирования главной страницы - нужно обратиться к части, где хранится визуальное оформление страницы (шаблон), это наш условный `View`. Но вот незадача, в этом коде шаблона есть цикл для вывода новостей, новости хранятся в БД, т.к. мы это знаем мы в контроллере дописываем логику которая обратится к `Model` и получит новости из бд. Модель - чаще всего представляет класс, который описывает один объект, например класс для работы с новостями. Собственно вот вам и `MVC`, если еще проще то можно сказать так: это 3 папочки, где в одной: файлы с логикой конкретных страниц (контроллер); в другой: файлы для работы с БД, каждый файл - отдельный объект (модели); В третьей: файлы с визуальным представлением (шаблоны).

Надеюсь мой пример был достаточно понятен, `MVC` - это просто идея, не более. У этой идеи есть куча реализаций и куча модификаций. Например то что я вам написал, это не классическая версия идеи, а доработанная практикой, классика подразумевает точку входа не контроллер, а `View`, который запрашивает самостоятельно контроллер и модель. Но и текущий пример это не пик, данная идея имеет ряд минусов, поэтому есть доработки, например `HMVC`.

Еще доступнее объяснить так: можно сравнить с автомобилем, есть идея: что двигатель крутит колеса, машина едет - все довольны. Идея простая, но реализаций куча, кто-то ставит двигатель спереди, кто-то сзади; кто-то крутит передние 2 колеса, кто-то задние, а кто-то и все 4. Но идея сохранена...

---

По вашему примеру, ни о каком `MVC` тут речи нет. Ваш пример ближе к классическому представлению, но я покажу более распространенный вариант:

Во-первых, обычно, классы `Model`, `Controller` используются как родители. Ведь контроллеров, моделей - много, поэтому у каждого свое название. Теперь по порядку:

Модель не модель - если она не содержит запросов к БД (может не содержать запросов (на практике), но в `MVC` модель подразумевает работу с БД):

```
class NewsModel extends Model
{
  public $text;

  public function __construct()
  {

    $this->text = <Запрос на получение текста из БД>;

  }
}
```

Отображение - это просто файлы нашего шаблона, класс `View` - является условным `шаблонизатором` и служит для того, чтобы вставить какие-то данные в этот шаблон:

```
class View
{
  public function render($file, $data)
  {

    // 1) найти файл $file
    // 2) загрузить его содержимое, и вставить в это содержимое $data
    // 3) вывести на экран

  }
}
```

Вставить содержимое, поясню что это, пусть есть массив:

```
$data = ['TITLE' => 'Заголовок'];
```

, в нашем примере - загрузка главной, шаблон пусть называется -`Home.tpl` и в нем есть строка:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% TITLE %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Главная страница
    </body>
</html>
```

Думаю логично что должно произойти, об этом и речь... Прошу не путать, и понимать что в концепции `MVC` отображением(view) - считается **не класс**, а именно наш `Home.tpl`

Ну и остался контроллер, его задача вызвать модельку, и отображение:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function HomeMain()
    {
        $this->loadNewModel('HomeModel');
        $data['TITLE'] = $this->HomeModel->text;
        $this->view->render('Home.tpl', $data);
    }
}
```

И осталось вызвать (за это отвечает роутинг):

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) AND ($_GET['action'] == 'HomeMain'))
{
    // загрузить файл с контроллером (HomeController)
    (new HomeController)->HomeMain();
}
```

P.S. Как вы могли заметить в контроллере есть методы: `$this->loadNewModel`, `$this->view` - эти функции из родительского класса (Controller). Описывать их реализацию я не буду, моя задача донести концепцию и думаю теперь вам все понятно...

Comment: Благодарю - самое вменяемое и простое описание. До меня эта "ИДЕЯ" тоже очень долго не доходила Кучу всего перечитал, слова и буквы понятные, но совершенно недоходило...

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вы в принципе не понимаете, как работают классы и объекты.
А работают они очень просто.
Когда вы создаете класс (давайте возьмем ваш пример) `Model`:

```
class Model {
  public $text;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->text = 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

В данном классе происходит инициализация свойства `$text` - это свойство объекта, а не статичная переменная или константа класса, она вызывается через контекст `$this->`, а не через `self::, static::`, когда бы она была `public static $text;`.
Когда вы определите объект в переменной:

```
$model = new Model();
```

У вас к свойству `$text` в конструкторе присваивается `$this->text = 'Hello World!';`
Так-как, свойство `public` (чего не рекомендуется делать, а лучше вернуть `getter`) вы сможете обратиться к этому свойству после передачи его другому объекту или сразу на экран:

```
echo $model->text;
```

В вашем случае, у вас `Model` определяется в конструкторе `Controller` и `View`, значит они принимают `Model`, который собран ранее:

```
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($model);
```

А раз мы отправляем в конструкторы классов, у нас будет доступно свойство `$text` в обоих классах, но операции можем делать разные.

У вас-же `View` выводит на экран, а `Controller` изменяет модель как нужно, допустим если вы обратитесь к адресу: `?action=textclicked` вызывает метод `$controller->{$_GET['action']}();` у Вас это `textClicked`, а дальше у вас в модели, изменится свойство `$text`, а `View` изменит вывод.

Answer (score 1):

https://phpdelusions.net/articles/mvc

На самом деле мвц - это очень просто. Реально просто. Надо только понимать, с какого конца за него браться.

А браться надо за модель.

Основная проблема в понимании мвц состоит в том, что люди воспринимают эти три компонента как равноправные, и одинаково важные. Но на самом деле единственным важным компонентом является модель. А контроллер и вью - это шелуха, два прыщика на упитанной и  румяной модели.

Модель - это вся логика приложения. Это и есть приложение. А контроллер и вью - это всего лишь один из способов обратиться запросить информацию у приложения, причем не обязательные. К примеру, если у нас REST API, то вью отсутствует как класс. А если мы обращаемся к приложению через командную строку, то нам не нужен контроллер.

Отсюда мы можем сделать несколько выводов

Модель - это не один класс, а целый набор классов. Которые и реализуют всю логику приложения.

Контроллер - это код, который служит для коммуникации между браузером и моделью. Он служит только для тансляции http запросов в команды модели.

Вью работает в паре с контроллером, если по запросу надо отобразить HTML.